# Use django pagination with SQL query and no ORM

Tags: sql-server, django, limit, django-pagination

I know how to use django pagination with ORM django after filtering the required data and put in into pagination div

```
queryset_list = employee.objects.all()
query=request.GET.get("q")
        if query:
            queryset_list=queryset_list.filter(
              Q(name__icontains=query)|
              Q(father_name__icontains=query)|
              Q(mother_name__icontains=query)|
              Q(content__icontains=query)|
              Q(create_date__icontains=query)
              # Q(user__first_name__contains=query)
            ).distinct()


        paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 5)
        page_request_var = "page"
        page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)
        queryset = paginator.get_page(page)

        context={
            "object_list":queryset,
            "title":"List Items",
            "page_request_var":page_request_var,
        }
        return render(request,"blog/list.html", context)
```

The above code is working

My question is how to convert this ORM into raw SQL

I know that I must use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` in raw SQL to embedded into paginator.

Comment: `LIMIT` is MySQL you want [`OFFSET` & `FETCH`](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-offset-fetch/)

Comment: @DaleBurrell okk i did not know that so i will try to search on fetch

Comment: Try the link I gave you - it has an example :)

Comment: ok so it say how to use offset and fetch in sql  server but how to use it with django pagination?

how to use the result of the query in the django pagination syntax
`paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 5)
        page_request_var = "page"
        page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)
        queryset = paginator.get_page(page)`